# flask / apache: serialized data not getting passed to Flask endpoint

Tags: javascript, ajax, apache, flask, jinja2

Have a somewhat complicated endpoint in Flask that is currently deployed to a server running the application under apache:

```
@app.route('/whatever', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def somefunct:
    if request.method == 'POST':
        templist = request.data.split("=", 1)
        << do some stuff with templist >>

    << do some other stuff >>
    return render_template('sometemplate.html', **<<variable dict>>)
```

sometemplate.html is kind of tricky, it contains a table that pulls data from the variable dictionary and also provides a dropdown that allows the user to interact with it, leveraging Jinja for variables:

```
{% for item in << variable in dict >> %}

...

<td>
    <form name="category-form" id="category-form-{{ item }}" action="/whatever">
        <select name="{{ item }}" id="{{ item }}">
            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</td>
```

and then I have some javascript to trigger the right POST action (jQuery is loaded):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    {% for item in << variable in dict >> %}

    var form{{ item }} = $('category-form-{{ item }}');

    form{{ item }}.find('#{{ item }}').change(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: form{{ item }}.attr('action'),
            data: form{{ item }}.serialize(),
            success: function(response){
                console.log("calling {{item}}")
            }
        });
    });

    {% endfor %}
});
```

I've done testing and can see that whenever an `item`'s form is called, it is successfully sending a `POST` action to the correct endpoint.

I can also see that it is serializing the right object, i.e. `319832=2`.

For some reason, the serialized object is not getting passed to the endpoint correctly -- `templist` is an empty object in Flask.

Guessing this is something to do with the handshake between the ajax call and the receipt of the `request` by the endpoint. Any ideas why the endpoint might not be receiving this request in an apache context, while the above works on my `localhost`?

Comment: should that say `if request.method == 'POST'`?

Comment: yup, thanks. error in transcribing, not code.

Comment: Is it going into `request.form` instead of `request.data`? That could be triggered by the value of `request.headers['Content-Type']`, which could be coerced in the JQuery call if it's not what Flask expects.

Comment: ah ok, I'll check, so I could find the same data in `request.form` in that case? the odd thing here is that this is all working fine on my dev machine and only started acting up after I pushed this to my company server.

Comment: yup this did it, guess apache did something weird with `request.headers`